# Tem como criptografar o banco da versão embedded do Firebird?

Tags: banco-de-dados, criptografia, firebird

Pretendo usar a versão embedded do Firebird em meu servidor de aplicação. Existe alguma forma de criptografar e usar esse banco como no SQLite?

Comment: Qual o propósito dessa criptografia? Segundo o [FAQ do Firebird](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq160/) (*acho* que também se aplica à versão embutida), não há suporte nativo à criptografia nesse banco, é necessário usar alguma solução externa. Se seu propósito for só proteger os dados "inativos" (i.e. quando seu sistema estiver desligado) você pode criptografar o disco/partição/volume virtual usando algum software como o TrueCrypt, e colocar os dados do banco nele. Isso não os protege enquanto o sistema está ativo, entretanto (pois o volume está montado, e os dados acessíveis em formato plano).

Comment: Você *poderia* encriptar os dados na camada de aplicação antes de guardar no banco, mas há algumas desvantagens (mais informações no FAQ), e um problema central: onde você guardaria a chave? Pois seu sistema precisa da chave para acessar os dados, de modo que se um atacante obtiver acesso a ele ele também terá acesso à chave... Há uns poucos cenários nos quais isso faz sentido, mas em geral proteger corretamente os dados é uma tarefa muito difícil.